# Failed to parse transaction from blob; failed to validate transaction from daemon

Tags: daemon, transaction-confirmation, monero-wallet-rpc

I'm trying to run on testnet using:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file MyWallet --daemon-address testnet.xmrchain.net:28081 --rpc-bind-port 28081 --testnet --disable-rpc-login
```

I tried getting testnet XMR coins from http://dis.gratis

However, all I get is this:

```
2018-01-12 21:06:37.197 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:06:37.197 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:07:01.520 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:07:01.520 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:07:26.146 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:07:26.146 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:07:50.273 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:07:50.273 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:08:14.476 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:08:14.476 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:08:38.654 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:08:38.654 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:51:15.598 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:51:15.598 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:51:39.712 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:51:39.712 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:52:03.248 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:52:03.248 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:52:26.880 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:52:26.880 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:52:50.532 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:52:50.532 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:53:13.983 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:53:13.983 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:53:37.508 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:53:37.508 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:57:05.055 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:57:05.055 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:57:29.064 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:57:29.064 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:57:53.137 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:57:53.137 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:58:17.148 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:58:17.149 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:58:41.278 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:58:41.278 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
2018-01-12 21:59:05.129 [RPC0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:123    Failed to parse transaction from blob
2018-01-12 21:59:05.129 [RPC0]  WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1585 failed to validate transaction from daemon
^C2018-01-13 00:45:44.712   [SRV_MAIN]  WARN    wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1900   Stopped wallet rpc server
2018-01-13 00:45:44.712 [SRV_MAIN]  WARN    wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1903   Storing wallet...
2018-01-13 00:45:45.240 [SRV_MAIN]  WARN    wallet.rpc  src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1905   Stored ok
```

And no coins since yesterday :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Monero testnet forked to v7 a month ago or so. If you're using an older monero-wallet-cli, it doesn't have code to recognize v7 blocks or bulletptroofs (which are the main change). You'll have to use a recent wallet. Be aware that there will be a testnet reorg where v7 consensus rules will change to save some more space and make bulletproofs a little safer still.

Comment: Should I build a bleeding edge cli bin which supports v7? Because I cant use the GUI on a headless setup

Comment: If you want to use testnet, yes. There are nodes still on v6 though, but since seed nodes are on v7, they're hard to find now :)